# firstOrderLogic - ∃xy.(P(x) ∧ ¬P(y))

Tags: discrete-mathematics, first-order-logic

I'm trying to make a model to satisfy the following formula

```
∀xyz.((R(x,y) ∧ R(y,z)) → R(z,z))
∃xy.(P(x) ∧ ¬P(y))
∀x ∃y.(R(x,y) ∧ x ≠ y)
```

I made this.

```
D= {Susan, George, Bob, Emma, Sara, Ryan, Jacob}
I(P) = {Susan, George, Bob, Emma}
I(R) = {〈George, Emma〉, 〈Emma, Bob〉, 〈Bob, Bob〉, 〈Bob, Emma〉, 〈Emma, Emma〉, 〈Susan, Jacob〉}
```

But I don't know how to make P be satisfied!! and what does "∃xy.(P(x) ∧ ¬P(y))" mean exactly!

Thanks in advance

Comment: The smallest model seems to have tho objects $A,B$ with $P(A)$, $R(A,A)$, $R(A,B)$, $R(B,A)$, $R(B,B)$

Comment: Should the last predicate in your first formula read `R(x,z)` instead of `R(z,z)`, or is `R(z,z)` indeed correct?

Comment: In my comments I was assuming the first formula ends with $R(x,z)$.  I misread the question

Comment: ya, the last predicate in first formula is R(z,z)

Answer (score 1):

$\exists xy.(P(x) \wedge \lnot P(y))$ means there are two items in your universe such that $P$ is true about one and false about the other.  Your set $I(P)$ looks like the items for which $P$ is true, so you have $P(Susan)$ and $\lnot P(Ryan)$ and the statement is satisfied in your model.

Your model does not satisfy the first and third statements.  For the third, there is no pair $R(Jacob, y)$ with $y$ different from Jacob.

Comment: thnks, in the last statement, x as the first item of R, has at least one y which is not equal to x. but in the model I defined, Jacob is the second item in R, not the first. is this interpretation true?

Comment: In your model Jacob is the second item in one of the elements of $R$, but the third statement requires that every $x$ be the first item in an element of $R$ and that the second item in that element be different from $x$.  You do not have a pair in $R$ that satisfies this for $x=Jacob$ (among others)

Comment: You mean all items in D, must be in the first item of R??

Comment: Is the following model true?? `D= {George, Bob, Emma}
I(P) = {George, Bob}
I(R) = {〈George, Emma〉, 〈Emma, Bob〉, 〈Bob, Bob〉, 〈Bob, Emma〉, 〈Emma, Emma〉}`

Comment: Please be careful.  $R$ is a set of ordered pairs and a set has no order. It doesn't make sense to talk of the first item of $R$.  It does make sense to talk of the first item in one of the ordered pairs.  That aside, yes, all items in $D$ must be the first item in at least one element of $R$.  One can be less pedantic once you are comfortable with this, but I think it helps in learning.  Your new model satisfies the second and third, but not the first requirement.

Comment: `D = {George, Bob, Emma}     I(P) = {George, Bob}     I(R) = {〈Bob, George〉, 〈George, Emma〉, 〈Emma, Bob〉, 〈Bob, Bob〉, 〈Bob, Emma〉, 〈Emma, Emma〉, 〈George, George〉}`   I think it satisfies all, right??

Comment: No because (George,Bob) is missing, which will force one more.  That will get you the relation that includes all the pairs, which is a fine solution.

Comment: Got it, thanks a lot 

Comment: `D = {George, Bob, Emma}
I(P) = {George, Bob}
I(R) = {〈George, Bob〉, 〈Bob, George〉, 〈George, Emma〉, 〈Emma, George〉, 〈Emma, Bob〉, 〈Bob, Emma〉, 〈Emma, Emma〉, 〈George, George〉, 〈Bob, Bob〉}
`

Comment: Yes, that works.  You could make it work with just two people to save typing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do with the names, but on first glance the third formula isn't satisfied: taking $x$ to be Sara, Ryan, or Jacob makes it false.

In general wouldn't it be easier to use $\mathbb{Z}$ as your universe? Interpret the binary relation as the standard partial order and the unary relation (that's what $P(x)$ stands for - essentially just a subset of the chosen universe) as the property of being odd. Then, written in more convenient notation, our formulas become:

$$\forall x,y,z\text{ }\big((x\leq y\text{ } \land y\leq z)\to z\leq z\big) \\
\exists x,y\text{ } (Odd(x) \text{ }\land \neg Odd(y)) \\
\forall x \exists y\text{ } (x\leq y\text{ }\land x\neq y)$$
I think these are easily seen to be satisfied. Hopefully the odd-not odd example clarifies what confusion you had with the second statement.